# Voids in steel?

Tags: metals

I have found black areas in the the surface of some steel. Are these voids from the original manufacure or are they created by corrosion?

This one is approx 1mm x 0.5mm.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: From those pictures it really isn't possible to tell. Voids seems unlikely, some machining issues might explain it, as would some surface corrosion. Without better metallography it is hard to say.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a slag inclusion, left over from the rolling operation in the mill. This is common in low-grade hot-rolled steels.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. The object is an air rifle barrel. The supplier is saying it's corrosion, but it looks to me to be inside the steel and exposed by the machining.

Comment: the next thing to do would be to either cut it up & put it in a scanning electron microscope for a closer look, or electropolish it and then do a grain boundary etch to see if there's evidence for intergranular corrosion. Do you have money to spend on this?

Comment: Hi Niels, alas not. I agree that sectioning it would show 100% that it's not corrosion caused by bad ownership but I don't really want to destroy the barrel... It's currently fitted with a bonded on carbon fibre sleve, so if that was removed and there were pits in the surface underneath, that would prove it's not corrosion too.

Comment: I see. how old is the barrel?

Comment: I would guess it's about 8 years old.

Comment: Some more photos added.

Comment: looking more to me now like intergranular or pitting corrosion, from storage in the damp, but can't be sure.